# class "org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Tags: java, maven, itext, digital-signature, bouncycastle

Can someone help me with this exception?  Does this mean that I have to run keytool with the java version of 1.5?

I had it working before, but now I get this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.CertificateInfo.getSubjectFields(CertificateInfo.java:356)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.getAppearance(PdfSignatureAppearance.java:884)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.preClose(PdfSignatureAppearance.java:1268)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.signDetached(MakeSignature.java:140)
at org.deloitte.cms.efi.controller.signature.SignatureAppearance.sign4(SignatureAppearance.java:181)
at org.deloitte.cms.efi.controller.signature.SignatureAppearance.main(SignatureAppearance.java:208)
```

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

This is my code:

```
    public void sign4(String src, String name, String dest,
        Certificate[] chain, PrivateKey pk,
        String digestAlgorithm, String provider, CryptoStandard subfilter,
        String reason, String location)
                throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {
    // Creating the reader and the stamper
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
    // Creating the appearance
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    //appearance.setReason(reason);
    //appearance.setLocation(location);
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(name);
    // Default text and scaled background image
    appearance.setImage(Image.getInstance(IMG));
    //appearance.setImageScale(-1);
    appearance.setImageScale(0);
    // Creating the signature
    PrivateKeySignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
    ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, subfilter);
}
```

This is my pom.xml

```
       <dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.6</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
       <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
       <version>1.52</version>
    </dependency>      
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
       <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
       <version>1.52</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This sounds like you have multiple BouncyCastle versions on your class path, not only the version you have declared as dependency.

Answer (score 6):

Please check your maven dependency tree. Your pom requests bc version 1.5.2, but according to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.6 , itext expects version 1.49. Remove the two bc elements from your pom.

Comment: Thanks you save my life :-)